# Share CGColor between iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-graphics

I'm writing a Core Graphics Cross Plattform Library for OSX and iOS.

I'm porting it over from an existing iOS Project where I created the `UIColor CGColor`attribute.
Of course UIColor is not available on the mac.

So whats the right way to use the same color on both systems?
Should i get the rgb value of all previously used `UIColor`s and create `CGColor`s programmtically or should I divide the code with `TARGET_OS_MAC` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` ifdefs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach is to avoid `UIColor` and `NSColor` altogether, and simply use `CGColorRef` wherever possible.

Core Animation is the best/most modern way to draw on both iOS and OS X. It expects `CGColorRef` objects and is (pretty much) cross platform.

The only drawback is, being a lower level data type, ARC doesn't handle memory management for you. But manual memory management isn't that hard.

Usage of CGColorRef:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat componennts[4] = {255, 255, 255, 255}; // white, with 100% opacity. Use {0,0,0,255} for black, or {255,0,0,127.5} for red with 50% opacity.
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, componennts);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);

layer.backgroundColor = color; // layer is a CALayer object
CGColorRelease(color);
```

You could avoid creating/releasing the color space object by storing it in a static variable:

```
static CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)initialize
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  });
}

- (void)blah
{
    CGFloat componennts[4] = {255, 255, 255, 255}; // white, with 100% opacity. Use {0,0,0,255} for black, or {255,0,0,127.5} for red with 50% opacity.
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(space, componennts);

    layer.backgroundColor = color; // layer is a CALayer object
    CGColorRelease(color);
```

Comment: Do you have an example usage for `CGColorRef`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
#ifndef UIColor
#define UIColor NSColor
#endif
```

Comment: This won't work because NSColor doesn't have an CGColor attribute

Comment: add it in a category!

Comment: @vikingosegundo clever - didn't think about it at first

Comment: I would not add it to a category. OS X 10.10 beta 1 will probably ship at WWDC and is highly likely to have the method that exists on iOS, and your category will probably break things in unpredictable ways. Instead, I would create a compiler macro if you want to go down that route.

Comment: @arnoapp: As of 10.8, it does (did)!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an alias on macOS

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
    import UIKit
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
    import AppKit

    public typealias UIColor = NSColor
#endif

public protocol Theme {
    var tint: UIColor { get }
    ...
}
```